# What are the definitions for these spaces: $AC\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right) ;$ $W^{1,p}\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right) ;$?

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Can anybody please tell me where can I find the proper definitions for the
following spaces? I have been looking on the internet and in other books and
have not found clear definitions for all these concepts. They are: $AC\left( %
\left[ a,b\right] ;X\right) ;$ $W^{1,p}\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right) ;$
$L^{p}\left( a,b;X\right)$, where  $X$ is a Banach space.

What I found is a definition for $L^{p}\left( a,b;X\right) $ that goes like
this:

Let $1\leq p\leq \infty .$ We will denote by $L^{p}\left( a,b;X\right) $ the
space of measurable functions $u:\left[ a,b\right] \rightarrow X,$ that have
the property that
\begin{equation*}
\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left( a,b;X\right) }=\left(
\int_{a}^{b}\left\Vert u\left( t\right) \right\Vert _{X}^{p}\,dt\right) ^{%
\frac{1}{p}}<\infty .
\end{equation*}

And I also found a definition for $W^{1,p}\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right)$ that goes like
this:
\begin{equation*}
W^{1,p}\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right) =\left\{ u\in AC\left( \left[ a,b%
\right] ;X\right) ;\frac{du}{dt}\in L^{p}\left( \left[ a,b\right] ;X\right)
\right\} .
\end{equation*}

Does anyone have a different definition for $L^{p}\left( a,b;X\right) $ and what about the other spaces?

Comment: The first one is probably the space of absolutely continuous functions on $[a,b]$, and the second one is probably a Sobolev space consisting of $L^p$ functions whose weak derivatives of order 1 also belong to $L^p$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: For $L^p$ you would also have to mod out by the equivalence relation given by almost everywhere equality.

Comment: You should mention in your question what $X$ is.